# Android: Media Player not pausing in second activity using ImageView

Tags: java, android

I have spent almost the day trying to figure it out and yet could not manage to achieve it. I basically have two activities, `MainActivity.java` and `GameActivity.java`. The music stops but after going back to `MainActivity.java` and coming back to `GameActivity.java` using `ImageView` several times.

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView iv;
public static final String BG_SOUND_CHECK = "background playing!";
//  public static MediaPlayer backgroundSound;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final MediaPlayer backgroundSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.background_music);


handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        backgroundSound.setLooping(true);
        backgroundSound.start();
        Log.v(BG_SOUND_CHECK, "After loop Started!");

    }
}, 3000);


getSupportActionBar().hide();
iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.playImage);
iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view1){
//                backgroundSound.setLooping(false);
                backgroundSound.pause();
//                Log.v(BG_SOUND_CHECK, "Playing After Play Button Click");
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
//         myIntent.putExtra("backgroundSoundObj",backgroundSound);
                startActivity(myIntent);
//                Log.v(BG_SOUND_CHECK, "After Game Scene");

    }
});


 }
}
```

> GameActivity.java

```
   public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    //        MainActivity.backgroundSound.pause();

    //   Rest of the code
    }
    }
```

I tried putting the music `onPause();` in 
1) ImageView onClick();
2) As soon as the GameActivity.java is loaded

but both ways end up pausing it only after I try coming back to `MainActivity.java` and going to `GameActivity.java` several times.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see how you put your `backgroundSound.start()` inside the postDelayed-3000 ?

`backgroundSound.pause()` anytime before that 3000ms is not going to do anything.

It has nothing to do with going back and forth between your two activities, it just so happens that doing that takes up more than 3000ms, so when you do click for pause(), 3000ms has passed.

What you can do, to fit your current code, is to separate that into a Runnable.

```
Runnable bgSound = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        backgroundSound.setLooping(true);
        backgroundSound.start();
        Log.v(BG_SOUND_CHECK, "After loop Started!");
    }
}
```

Use it with `handler.postDelayed(bgSound, 3000)`

In your `onClick`, if you want to stop it from playing before it starts, can use `handler.removeCallbacks(bgSound)`, to stop it after it plays, your `pause()`. If you don't care to know if it has or hasn't started, you can do both alongside each other, should work fine too.

(if you don't want the music to play after you've left your main activity, you should also do the same actions in your `onDestroy` and/or `onPause`)

Comment: But I want the background music to start after 3000ms since I have a splash screen before this that take 3000ms to display some animation. I tried this, doesn't work.

Comment: `handler.postDelayed(bgSound, 3000)` does just that. Then you should be more clear about when/where you want your music to pause/stop.

Comment: Starting the music isn't a problem. Pausing it, is!